# How to jump backward in final fight?

Tags: final-fight

I am playing final fight arcade via some means. It's my favorite game when I was a kid.

I look at how others play. I see that Hagar can jump backward.

How can hagar does that? And what's the point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"To jump backwards, a specific input is required, since simply holding a direction and pressing jump would result in the character facing that direction and jumping forward. After pressing jump with no directional input, the game will wait in a pre-jump animation for a few frames. If you then press back, your character will jump backwards instead of forward. Backwards jumps are a bit limited in that you cannot perform a standard jumping attack, but all characters can perform their jumping down attack to maintain at least some attack and space control option."

https://kb.speeddemosarchive.com/Final_Fight/Basics